# How to save the sortable list Order

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, sortables

I'm using meteor platform. I have developed a dash board.[image: Here each job1,job2,job3 under project are sortable.smitha,...test1 are dashboard Names]

Now iI want to save the order of sorted list when user click save button and display in the same order that he had saved.

I achieved sortable using Dragula package.

status.js

```
Template.status.events({
'click .outr':function(){
  var drake=dragula([document.querySelector('.sortable-items')]);  
  },
});
```

status.html

```
<div class="ui bottom attached segment" style="border-radius:0.5em;margin-left:0.0%; overflow:hidden;padding:0 0 0 0;">
  <div class="ui menu grids vbox " style="border-radius:0.5em;margin-top:0; overflow:hidden;" id="vbox">
    {{#each getDash}}      
      <div class=" column equal width aligned padded center aligned outr">
        <div class="ui vertical allifluid small menu hand rock icon " style="background-color:lightgray;  border: 0.5px solid black;">
          <center><p class="handle" style="width:4 5 6 2">{{this.project}}</p></center>
          <div class="sortable-items" >
          {{#each listjobName project}}
            <div class="ui inverted small menu jbox" style="background-color:{{getStatusColor buildStatus}};   border: 1px solid black;">
            <p id="viewJob" class="under" ><h5>{{this.job}}</h5></p>
            </div>
          {{/each}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</div>
```

In status.html `this.project` and `this.job` fetch from Database using helper `getDash` and `listjobName` respectively.

Comment: Use jQuery to select them and add them to an array/list?

Comment: yes after saving into array/list i need to display it in same order.

Comment: I have more than one project(columns), so how can i get the order of project name and all the jobs in that project in an array?

Answer (score 0):

Just store the order inside a document in a collection.
For example you could use a Collection called Projects. And the data structure would look like that:

```
{
    _id: 'herh52rh48a6eh7a86e7hz'
     projectName: 'tes1';
     jobs : [
          {
               id: 54845 (Random generated id)
               name: 'job1',
               order: 1
          },
          {
               id: 87813
               name: 'job2',
               order: 2
          },
          {
               id: 54369
               name: 'job3',
               order: 3
          },
     ]
}
```

For each job, you have a field `order`:

You need to use the array 'jobs' to display your job list. And when you click on save you have to get the jobs and their order. And store it in the database.

I don't know how to do it with dragula, so i will let you find a way. Maybe this answer will give you an idea.

Comment: Will u please provide some more details? ,like how to fetch the order how can i udate my mongo db of meteor

Comment: @SmithaSHegade, you may want to consider keeping the scope of this question limited and post additional questions for your other issues, such as those relating to database structure and ORMs.